# Can I stream video and keep the sound?

Tags: chromecast

I have a Chrome Cast, which I am streaming video from my computer, using the Google plugin for Chrome, to my TV. The TV has the audio, but I would also like to keep the audio on the host device. The video shows up just fine. How might I accomplish this?

Comment: Play the video again on your laptop while it is also streaming to the ChromeCast.

Comment: Play it twice, with 3 video displays, is the only option?

Comment: You could split on the ChromeCast, then [split](http://readwrite.com/2013/07/30/chromecast-tips-tricks-workarounds-hacks-advice) it back to your laptop. But it would be cheaper and easier to just run a line out from the TV to speakers near you.